# Scrapy Data Table extract

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape `"https://www.expireddomains.net/deleted-com-domains/"`
for the expired domain data list.

I always get empty item fields for the following

```
class ExpiredSpider(BaseSpider):

    name = "expired"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.expireddomains.net/deleted-com-domains/']

    def parse(self, response):
        log.msg('parse(%s)' % response.url, level = log.DEBUG)
        rows = response.xpath('//table[@class="base1"]/tbody/tr')
        for row in rows:
            item = DomainItem()
            item['domain'] = row.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract()
            item['bl'] = row.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

Can somebody point out what is wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first note, you should use `scrapy.Spider` instead of BaseSpider which is deprecated

Secondly, `.extract()` method returns a list rather than a single element.
This is how the item extraction should look like

```
item['domain'] = row.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract_first()
item['bl'] = row.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract_first()
```

Also,

You should use the built in python `logging` library

```
import logging
logging.debug("parse("+response.url+")")
```